# How to deposit and withdraw WETH

Tags: solidity, wrapped-tokens

When I try to make a deposit, Ethereum is transferred but the Wrapped ether is not received. Here is my code

```
interface IWETH is IERC20 {
  receive() external payable;

  function deposit() external payable;

  function withdraw(uint256 wad) external;
}

contract Swap {
  address payable private constant  WETH =
    0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

  function wrapEther() external payable {
    uint256 ETHAmount = msg.value;

    //create WETH from ETH
    if (msg.value != 0) {
      IWETH(WETH).deposit{ value: ETHAmount }();
    }
    require(
      IWETH(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)) >= ETHAmount,
      "Ethereum not deposited"
    );
  }

  function unwrapEther(uint256 Amount) external {
    address payable sender = msg.sender;

    if (Amount != 0) {
      IWETH(WETH).withdraw(Amount);
      sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
  }

}
```

hard-hat config

```
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "hardhat-contract-sizer";
const config = {
  defaultNetwork: "ganache",
  solidity: "0.7.6",
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./src/artifects",
  },
  networks: {
    ganache: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
    },
  },
  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 1,
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

here is the error after `unwrapEther` function is being called

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
"code": -32000,
"data": {
"stack": "c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n at Function.c.fromResults
```

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page:
In the code above, the WETH should end up in the Swap contract and not in the caller's wallet.

Comment: Hi, Actually it should end up in the caller's wallet. @AhmedIhsanTawfeeq

Comment: How are you deploying that contract? On mainnet? On a local fork? Or on a testnet?

Comment: @YahyaParvar if you want it to end up in the caller's wallet, you need to add another step to transfer the WETH from the swap contract to the owner's wallet. This would invalidate the "require" statement you have at the end of "wrapEther()".

Comment: On a local fork @Foxxxey

Comment: Wierd. It works just fine on my end (apart from the fact that it's the contract getting the WETH, and not the caller). Can you share what's inside your hardhat-config file? Or the config file of whatever framework you're using. @YahyaParvar

Comment: Yes sure @Foxxxey

Comment: Updated the question @Foxxxey

Comment: Made an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the implementation of `wrapEther()` as follows:

1. Add a step to transfer the minted WETH from the Swap contract to the caller's wallet.
2. Fix the require statement, since the original one had a bug when the caller already had a non-zero balance of WETH.

In a real-life scenario, you should not be using that require statement since it adds cost. Instead, you would test your contracts using a test framework to ensure the code provides the correct behavior.

```
function wrapEther() external payable {
    uint256 balanceBefore = IWETH(WETH).balanceOf(msg.sender);
    uint256 ETHAmount = msg.value;

    //create WETH from ETH
    if (ETHAmount != 0) {
      IWETH(WETH).deposit{ value: ETHAmount }();
      IWETH(WETH).transfer(msg.sender, ETHAmount);
    }
    require(
      IWETH(WETH).balanceOf(msg.sender) - balanceBefore == ETHAmount,
      "Ethereum not deposited"
    );
  }
```

As for `unwrapEther(...)`, you need to transfer the required WETH from the caller's wallet to the Swap contract before calling `withdraw(...)` as follows:

```
//Extremely important!!!!
receive() external payable {}

function unwrapEther(uint256 Amount) external {
    address payable sender = msg.sender;

    if (Amount != 0) {
      IWETH(WETH).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), Amount);
      IWETH(WETH).withdraw(Amount);
      sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
  }
```

But before calling `unwrapEther(...)`, the caller's wallet needs to approve the Swap contract to spend `Amount` WETH tokens on its behalf. You can go to the [WETH contract page via Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2#writeContract), connect the caller wallet via Metamask, and then call `approve` by providing the Swap contract address in `guy` field and `Amount` in `wad` field.

Comment: @YahyaParvar I've updated my answer to include `unwrapEther`

Comment: It gets reverted even though I approved to send the WETH from ERC20 `approve function`

Comment: @YahyaParvar could you send me the link to the failed transaction?

Comment: Also, make sure that `Amount` is less than or equal to the caller's WETH balance.

Comment: The transaction is happening on a local fork of mainnet therefore I don't think we can access the link since it's not available on etherscan or something similar. But I added the error message to the updated question :)

Comment: @YahyaParvar Sorry I don't see why the method call should fail. Just make sure you're approving the correct address and from the correct wallet. Maybe also set the approve amount to the maximum possible just to make sure you're approving enough allowance.

Comment: Ok I will do that and try more. I'll let you know what was the problem

Comment: Hi @AhmedIhsanTawfeeq. In UnwrapEther why `sender.transfer(address(this).balance); ` instead of transferring only amount?

Comment: It makes no difference unless the contract already had a balance of ETH when the function is called. Personally, I'd rather use `Amount ` instead of `address(this).balance` just to make the behavior more defined.

Comment: Hey @AhmedIhsanTawfeeq, It's been a while. But I just realized we should have implemented `receive() external payable {}` inside body of the contract

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your contract, it's giving the same thing, the total balance doesn't change after swap. I'm still trying, but have you tried using another contract? I tested this one, and it works pretty good:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract WETHSwap {
    string public name = "Wrapped Ether";
    string public symbol = "WETH";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    event Approval(address indexed src, address indexed guy, uint256 wad);
    event Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint256 wad);
    event Deposit(address indexed dst, uint256 wad);
    event Withdrawal(address indexed src, uint256 wad);

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    function() public payable {
        deposit();
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 wad) public {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= wad);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= wad;
        msg.sender.transfer(wad);
        Withdrawal(msg.sender, wad);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return this.balance;
    }

    function approve(address guy, uint256 wad) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][guy] = wad;
        Approval(msg.sender, guy, wad);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address dst, uint256 wad) public returns (bool) {
        return transferFrom(msg.sender, dst, wad);
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address src,
        address dst,
        uint256 wad
    ) public returns (bool) {
        require(balanceOf[src] >= wad);

        if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint256(-1)) {
            require(allowance[src][msg.sender] >= wad);
            allowance[src][msg.sender] -= wad;
        }

        balanceOf[src] -= wad;
        balanceOf[dst] += wad;

        Transfer(src, dst, wad);

        return true;
    }
}
```

It wasn't me who did it, I found it in some library in github.
Hope this helps

Comment: Well this is just another WETH contract. I believe OP wants to interact with the actual WETH contract deployed at 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, not make its own version

Comment: That is correct. @Foxxxey

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But actually I wanted to call the actual WETH contract and not writing one on my own :)

Comment: Awesome... I was still looking, and I found out something. When you do the swap, the Balance stay in your New Deployed Contract, so you need add one more step to just after swap, your contract transer the WETh amout to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The chain you're deploying on is an empty chain, not a mainnet fork. The WETH contract doesnt exist on that chain if you don't deploy it. Read https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks

EDIT : Here's the fixed code :

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

interface IWETH is IERC20 {

  function deposit() external payable;

  function withdraw(uint256 wad) external;
}

contract Swap {
  address private constant  WETH =
    0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

  function wrapEther() external payable {
    uint256 ETHAmount = msg.value;

    //create WETH from ETH
    if (msg.value != 0) {
      IWETH(WETH).deposit{ value: ETHAmount }();
    }
    require(
      IWETH(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)) >= ETHAmount,
      "Ethereum not deposited"
    );
    // transfer will do, you don't need to use transferFrom, use it only when the tokens you want to transfer arent held by the contract (like in unwrapEther())  
    IWETH(WETH).transfer(msg.sender, IWETH(WETH).balanceOf(address(this)));
  }
  
  // To receive ETH from the WETH's withdraw function (it won't work without it) 
  receive() external payable {}
  
  
  function unwrapEther(uint256 Amount) external {
    address payable sender = payable(msg.sender);
    if (Amount != 0) {
      // Taking tokens from a wallet require allowance, look up https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20#methods, especially the paragraphs on transferFrom() and approve()
      require(IWETH(WETH).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= Amount, "insufficient allowance");
      IWETH(WETH).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), Amount);
      IWETH(WETH).withdraw(Amount);
      sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm running `npx ganache-cli -f https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/f758ee8390c4409b969064ae326b082d`. Other contracts exist on the network. I think problem is with something else what do you think?

Comment: Oh, wierd. Well it should work then, as far as i can see. Does the transaction completes, or does it revert when you call wrapEther?

Comment: It does get completed. But the wrapped ether is not in caller's wallet lol

Comment: Oh, well yeah that's normal, it's in the contract. I'll edit my answer with the fixed code, just give me a min :)

Comment: Don't you think we should transfer the WETH to sender's waller via calling `transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender)` ?

Comment: Answered that in my edit :)